# Mac Audio Cuts Out Randomly - thoughts?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, audio, osx-mavericks

Recently, several colleagues and I have noticed an issue with our Macs - the audio will cut out at random and cannot be attained unless a user restarts their computer. Some Google-fu shows the issue is apparent when audio is played from Chrome for a long time of time or flash. Google chrome has been the culprit in our case. Below are the specs:

1. Mac OS X 10.92
2. Typically happens in a day while with chrome playing audio
3. Audio can go out if User does not restart their computer
4. I have gone into system preferences and attempted to change the outputs as well as toggle with headphones and builtin speakers - result = fail.

Anybody have any experience resolving this issue?

thanks,

Comment: I have a similar problem as a user rather than rebooting I just open a terminal and enter `sudo killall coreaudiod`

Comment: Will this process cause any unintended consequences with other running programs? I wish there was a way to test it immediately and not have to wait until the next time. :)

Comment: I don't know of any consequences. For me, it happens while watching netflix with Chrome. After I run the kill command, the audio resumes and everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved in the latest version of Mavericks. Since installing 10.9.4, i have not had any issues.